# UFuncTypeError when trying to input

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am getting a (below) error when I try to input values, but not when I assign them statically, and I don't really know why.

I am trying to input values for inn and out. I get the error code, but I don't really know how to fix it.

---

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

  File "C:\Users\sveng\Desktop\HabitableZone.py", line 11, in <module>
    xs = np.outer(radii, np.cos(theta))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in outer

  File "C:\Users\sveng\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 906, in outer
    return multiply(a.ravel()[:, newaxis], b.ravel()[newaxis, :], out)
```

---

**Working Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inn=.95
out=1.37

n, radii = 50, [inn, out]

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=True)
xs = np.outer(radii, np.cos(theta))
ys = np.outer(radii, np.sin(theta))

# in order to have a closed area, the circles
# should be traversed in opposite directions
xs[1,:] = xs[1,::-1]
ys[1,:] = ys[1,::-1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.fill(np.ravel(xs), np.ravel(ys),color='pink')

star = plt.Circle((0, 0), .25, color='yellow')
earthorbit = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='black', fill=False,linestyle='-',linewidth=2)
inner = plt.Circle((0, 0), inn, color='red', fill=False,linestyle='--',linewidth=2)
outer = plt.Circle((0, 0), out, color='blue', fill=False,linestyle='--',linewidth=2)

ax.add_artist(earthorbit)
ax.add_artist(inner)
ax.add_artist(outer)
ax.set_facecolor('black')
ax.add_artist(star)

plt.show()
```

**Error Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inn=input("Enter inner radial value (in AU): ")
out=input("Enter inner radial value (in AU): ")


n, radii = 50, [inn, out]

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=True)
xs = np.outer(radii, np.cos(theta))
ys = np.outer(radii, np.sin(theta))

# in order to have a closed area, the circles
# should be traversed in opposite directions
xs[1,:] = xs[1,::-1]
ys[1,:] = ys[1,::-1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.fill(np.ravel(xs), np.ravel(ys),color='pink')

star = plt.Circle((0, 0), .25, color='yellow')
earthorbit = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='black', fill=False,linestyle='-',linewidth=2)
inner = plt.Circle((0, 0), inn, color='red', fill=False,linestyle='--',linewidth=2)
outer = plt.Circle((0, 0), out, color='blue', fill=False,linestyle='--',linewidth=2)

ax.add_artist(earthorbit)
ax.add_artist(inner)
ax.add_artist(outer)
ax.set_facecolor('black')
ax.add_artist(star)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's saying that it can't multiply two string arrays. '<U32' is a unicode string dtype.

Comment: Check `radii` and `theta`.  Are they really numbers, or are they strings?

Comment: Ah they are strings, aren't they. I didn't think of it that way.

Answer (score 0):

What you write to the input is saved as a `string` value, but I think you need an `float`, try something like:

```
inn=float(input("Enter inner radial value (in AU): "))
```

Comment: When I do this, I get:

File "C:\Users\sveng\Desktop\HabitableZone.py", line 4, in <module>
    inn=int(input("Enter inner radial value (in AU): "))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.95'

Comment: Then: inn = float(input("Enter inner radial value (in AU): "))